# Is there a way to put only needed parts of a denpendency in maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

In my project i use some dependencies that must be in my final jar, so i use maven-assembly-plugin to create a fat jar. However there is no reason to place all the dependency packages in the final jar.

e.g.:
In a dependency N, there are packages A and B. The package A contains the classes X and Y, and the package B contais the classes Z and K. In my plugin I use the class X, which is correlated with the class Y,  so, there is no reason to put the package B and it's classes in my final jar, only the package A.

Comment: Do you want Only some jar files or do you only want part of one or more jar file?

Comment: @Thorbjørn i want that only the used part of one or more jar files to be included in my final jar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to include only the used classes in a war file with maven build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884795/is-it-possible-to-include-only-the-used-classes-in-a-war-file-with-maven-build)

Comment: @aleZalazar yes, thank you.